# How to get value of Integer object in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement Integer#times, but don't know how to know the
value of an Integer object. So I am doing it like this:

```
class Integer
  def times
    n = (self.next) -1
    x = 1
    while x <= n
      yield(x)
      x += 1
    end
  end
end
```

I am using (self.next) -1 to get the value of the object:)
I know it is not the right way of doing it. How to get the value
of the Integer object?

Comment: thanks. that works. i was thinking about that but didn't try, i thought self
is object. i am confused about the object and it's value.

Comment: The value of an integer is that same integer. `x = 1; x.equal?(x.to_i)` is `true`.  In fact, the definition of `Integer#to_i` is `static VALUE int_to_i(VALUE num) { return num; }` (equivalent to `def to_i; self; end` in Ruby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use `self` as mentioned by [messanjah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597358/messanjah).

Note: if you try `object.methods` in ruby console for an int like `5.methods`, you can find all the methods the object supports like `to_i` and `to_int` which also returns the value of the int object
so, you can try `self.to_int`